# Getting links with loop then using .get displays one image

Tags: jquery, get

```
$(function() {
 $('.friends-foes-list a:first-child')
    .append('<img src="" class="ez_friend" />');
var href = $('div.friends-foes-list a:nth-child(1)').attr('href');

    for(var j=0;j<href.length;j++) {
      $.get(href[j] , function(data) { 
           var elem = $(data);
      $('.friends-foes-list .ez_friend')
         .attr('src',elem.find('#profile-advanced-right .main-content img') 
            .attr('src'));
       }, 'html');

     }
   });
```

I am trying to get each `.friends-foes-list a:nth-child(1)` url which the loop does perfectly. Though the issue now is that the `.get` grabs the urls gets the data I am searching for "displays them fast" and then shows the last image in each of the divs instead of showing the respectful image that needs to be shown per div...

Question now that I am writing this out, does the `.attr` inside the `.get` need to be in a loop as well to show each individual image to its respectful div?

If it does not need to be in a loop how would I go about this?

EDITED CODE FORGOT `.attr('href')` in the var

Comment: I don't get it? Are you using actual DOM elements as the URL in the ajax call ?

Comment: As noone seems to answer, try `$.get(href[j].href , function(data) { ...`

Comment: adeneo I will try, thank you for your reply. Yes I am using DOM elements as the URL as these are generated friends list created via PHP(which I don't have access to) So I need the work around.


@adeneo sorry this did not work :(

Comment: You can't use elements as the URL, $.get accepts a string only, and that string has to be a valid URL, normally on the same domain as JS does'nt support cross domain requests.

Comment: @adeneo my bad, I didn't mean DOM elements, better yet inside the scope of the element is the string of the url and it is same domain. Sorry if the wording is incorrect, I am still learning everything :)

Comment: Try something more like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/HqHgt/) ??

Comment: Adeneo same issue :( ugh. I will try and make a mock of what is going on, not sure too much on how to get the jsbin to work with this really since I am using .get

Comment: Here is a jsbin to sort of get what is going on i suppose... http://jsbin.com/upezul/1/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is with this selector:

```
$('.friends-foes-list .ez_friend')
         .attr('src',elem.find('#profile-advanced-right .main-content img') 
            .attr('src'));
```

The selector `.friends-foes-list .ez_friend` is going to find each one of the img tags you add in the beginning.  If you want to only add the image you `get` to the container that holds the anchor tag with the corresponding `href`, I would think something like this should work:

```
$(href[j]).find('.ez_friend')
         .attr('src',elem.find('#profile-advanced-right .main-content img') 
            .attr('src'));
```

This way it only finds the `.ez_friend` within the same container and not all other iteratiosn of that image class.

Of course as some of the comment hint at, you also need to grab the correct url from the anchor tag, something like:

```
$.get(href[j].attr('href') , function(data) { ...
```

Comment: yeah updated code as I forgot to write in the var .attr('href') ;) or maybe since I am getting /u /2 which it should be /u2 haha I will add it like you did to see what happens thank you

Comment: Still a bit buggy, as of right now I am not getting any images at all.

Comment: Ok so I am seeing my issue now, just don't know the fix. I alerted the urls and they are coming up as follows. u . 2. u. 3. u. 4 u. 5. Basically chopping each url in to two. Is there something I wrote wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like you are now looping through each character in your anchor tags href value.  I don't think you want to do that.  Why loop if you are only expecting the var `href` to be one element?

Comment: I am looping because I have a different image at each url. say this

/u1 has img src of "www.imagelocation.com/thisisimage1.png"
/u4 has img src of "www.imagelocation.com/thisisimage2.png"
/u5 has img src of "www.imagelocation.com/thisisimage6.png"

I mean this is the only way I believed I could each link url and each image

Comment: I do not understand what `/u1` is.  That does not look like any sort of valid HTML element or id/class selector.

Comment: I see, that was not clear to me reading the content above.  Does this help?  http://jsfiddle.net/rEZSk/

Comment: Yeah I am sorry I wasn't very clear ;) I can't really do an array, since I won't know the hrefs? Sorry first time doing this, do the arrays have to be preset data or?

Comment: No, the arrays can be a collection of elements returned from a jQuery selection.  For example, `$('div.friends-foes-list a:nth-child(1)')` should work.  But you want to grab the `href` inside of the loop like in my answer `$.get(href[j].attr('href')`.

Comment: ok. so can you make a fiddle so it alerts the urls for me. Sorry I'm learning still and just want to see it in action and am very busy or I'd take all day to fix it for myself :( Please don't think of me as I barely ever ask of this. I'd rather take what people tell me read it, learn it, study it, and keep writing it for a day so I can learn it and remember it. Please and thank you